# Highlight cells and header if value of a cell is changed from its original value

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, angular10

I am using primeng table cell edit. My code is as follows:

```
<div class="card">
    <p-table [value]="products" dataKey="id" [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:25%">Code</th>
                <th style="width:25%">Name</th>
                <th style="width:25%">Inventory Status</th>
                <th style="width:25%">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product let-editing="editing">
            <tr>
                <td [pEditableColumn]="product.code" pEditableColumnField="code">
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.code" />
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{ product.code }}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
                <td [pEditableColumn]="product.name" pEditableColumnField="name">
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" required />
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{ product.name }}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
                <td [pEditableColumn]="product.inventoryStatus" pEditableColumnField="inventoryStatus">
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input pInputText [(ngModel)]="product.inventoryStatus" />
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{ product.inventoryStatus }}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
                <td [pEditableColumn]="product.price" pEditableColumnField="price">
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.price" />
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{ product.price | currency: 'USD' }}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { ProductService } from '../../service/productservice';

@Component({
    selector: 'table-cell-edit-demo',
    templateUrl: 'table-cell-edit-demo.html'
})
export class TableCellEditDemo implements OnInit {
    products!: Product[];

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.productService.getProductsMini().then((data) => {
            this.products = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-cell-edit-demo.html

Cell Edit is working fine. I want to highlight with red color those particular cells and respective header in non editable mode if value of any particular cell is changed from it's original value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to colorize the edited cell in your component's HTML, you can follow these steps:

1. Add a template reference variable `#rows` to the `<tr>` element to read the rows using `@ViewChildren`. This will allow you to access the rows in your component.

   ```html
   <tr #rows>
   ```
2. Modify the `<td>` elements where you want to track edits by adding an `[id]` attribute. The `[id]` attribute should be set as a combination of the property and the rowIndex, for example: `[id]="'name'+index"`.

   ```html
   <td pEditableColumn [id]="'name' + ri">
   ```
3. Inside the `<input>` element that represents the editable field, add `(ngModelChange)` to listen for changes in the input value. When the value changes, call a method such as `colorizeEditedCell(rowIndex, fieldName)` and pass the `rowIndex` and `fieldName` as parameters.

   ```html
   <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" (ngModelChange)="colorizeEditedCell(ri,'name')" required />
   ```
4. Add an `@ViewChildren` decorator to your component class to read the rows using the template reference variable `#rows`:

   ```js
   @ViewChildren('rows') rows: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLTableRowElement>>;
   ```
5. Inject the `Renderer2` into your component's constructor to use it for manipulating the DOM:

   ```js
   constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2) {}
   ```
6. Define the `colorizeEditedCell` function in your component to set the background color of the edited cell. This function takes the `rowIndex` and `fieldName` as parameters.

   ```js
   colorizeEditedCell(rowIndex: number, fieldName: string) {
     const cols = this.rows.get(rowIndex).nativeElement.cells;
     for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols.length; colIndex++) {
       const col = cols.item(colIndex);
       if (col.id == fieldName + rowIndex) {
         this._renderer2.setStyle(col, 'backgroundColor', '#ececec');
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

The above code will iterate through the cells of the specified row and check if the `col.id` matches the provided `fieldName + rowIndex`. If a match is found, the `Renderer2` is used to set the background color of the cell to `#ececec`.

Note: Make sure to import the necessary dependencies such as `Renderer2` and `ElementRef` in your component file.

> There is an event called `onEditComplete` in the editable table
> component that you can utilize by adding certain properties to the
> `<td>` tag, as mentioned in the documentation. Here's an example:

> ```
> <td [pEditableColumn]="rowData"
> [pEditableColumnField]="'year'" [pEditableColumnRowIndex]="index">
> ```

> In the example above, `rowData` corresponds to the `product` in our
> case, and `'year'` represents the property of the product that this
> column is associated with. The `columnsRowIndex` property is set to
> the `index` value in our example.
>
> However, it's important to note that the `onEditComplete` event fires
> only when the input field loses focus (on blur). This means it won't
> notify you immediately if the data in the field changes without
> triggering the blur event.
>
> If you require real-time updates or want to track changes as the user
> types, you'll need to use other mechanisms, such as `(ngModelChange)`
> or `(input)` events, as shown in the previous code example.

***There might be alternative solutions available, but this approach should effectively address your requirements.***